# SSL Redirect & Subdomain Redirect

Tags: redirect

This is my .htaccess for my ssl.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This redirects my website to https, but i have one subdomain which is subdomain.mywebsite.com and when i apply this code in .htaccess it redirects my subdomain.mywebsite.com to -> https://mywebsite.com/subdomain

But i don't want it to redirect my subdomain to subfolder. So what i want is

https://subdomain.mywebsite.com

How can i fix this?